# Subir un proyecto angular a un servidor de produccion

Tags: angular

Quiero subir mi proyecto angular a un servidor de produccion, pero cuando ejecuto

```
>> ng build --prod
```

No me genera ningun error

```
Your global Angular CLI version (7.0.3) is greater than your local
version (6.1.3). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".

Date: 2018-11-01T16:05:43.076Z
Hash: 096eb3dcf5009220dbe2
Time: 34278ms
chunk {0} runtime.a66f828dca56eeb90e02.js (runtime) 1.05 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {1} styles.b00cb641b4deb8103af2.css (styles) 260 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {2} polyfills.945a753c7d5bef41f759.js (polyfills) 97.3 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {3} main.ddbaaa1d257c82ff16c5.js (main) 647 kB [initial] [rendered]
```

Luego copio la carpeta dist al servidor de produccion y cambio los respectivos links de js y css para que pueda ser llamado desde `miempresa.com/mi-proyecto-angular`
Logro mostrar a la perfeccion el idndex del proyecto pero cuando quiero tener acceso a los componentes creados,
`por ejemplo "contacto" http://miempresa.com/mi-projecto-angular/contacto`
no puedo por que me tira un error 404.

---

respuesta:
Tienes que compilar utilizando el siguiente comando:
tu ruta de proyecto angular: https://tuweb/tucarpetaenweb/

ng build --base-href=/tucarpetaenweb/

Saludos

Comment: En este momento tengo el mismo error, si tuviste la respuesta de como hacerlo ¿Podrías compartir la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

aún no tengo la reputación suficiente para hacer comentarios, así que lo pondré como una respuesta.

Ponle a tu index.html lo siguiente:

```
<base href="./">
```

Para que te reconozca los componentes en tu ruta actual.
Si no te funciona, muestra tu index.html, y el mensaje de error que te está saliendo.

Comment: Kevin el problem no estaria en el index, <base href="./"> asi es como lo tengo. Al index puedo verlo, lo que no puedo hacer es navegar por los modulos. Por ejemplo el modulo "contacto"